# Is this an error in the Google Actions documentation at the Runtime type overrides part?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am struggeling to get a response with an override from my own API.
And please correct me if the title within the documentation is wrong.

I am talking about [this part](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=builder#runtime_type_overrides) of the documentation.

It is about the "Runtime type overrides".
There you can choose between showing the code for NODE.JS or Request JSON.

But should it not be "Response JSON" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct. The docs have been updated and this issue is fixed. Hopefully the docs are clearer now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint and if you are part of the Google team, for your support!